# Reference request for recurrence relation of the complete Bell polynomials $B_n$

Tags: combinatorics, reference-request, recurrence-relations, recursion, bell-numbers

On [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_polynomials#Recurrence_relations) wikipedia page there is the following recurrence relation for the complete Bell polynomials $B_n$:
$$B_{n+1}(x_1,...,x_{n+1})=\sum_{i=0}^n\binom{n}{i}B_{n-i}(x_1,...,x_{n-i})x_{i+1}$$
with $B_0=1$.

I am trying to find a reference in form of a paper or book to cite this relation, but I was not able to find one. All the references on the wikipedia page (as far as I can see)
do not include it.

Any help is very much appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: You can find it in E. T. Bell's 1934 paper *Exponential Polynomials*. In that paper $B_n$ is denoted by $Y_n$. See, in particular, the formula between (7.11) and (7.12).

Comment: @Gary Oh, apparently I am going blind... Thank you very much!